# how to call a function from User.php

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to call the function below from my header.php. but i get an error. When i call it from my view file (profile.php) it works fine.

In my **/model/User.php**

```
public function getAvatar() {
         $dir = 'uploads/user';
         $img = $this->avatar_link;
         $full_img_dir = './'.$dir.'/'.$this->id.'/'.$img;
         return (!empty($this->avatar_link) && file_exists($full_img_dir)) 
                ? Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/'.$dir.'/'.$this->id.'/'.$img
                : Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/blank_profile.gif';
     }
```

here is the error i get

```
Property "UserController.avatar_link" is not defined.
```

and i'm calling the function like this

```
<img class="img-rounded user-avatar" src="<?php echo User::getAvatar(); ?>" title="<?php echo Yii::app()->user->username; ?>" />
```

This is my **models/User.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'users':
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $state
 * @property string $postcode
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $activate
 * @property string $last_login
 * @property string $password_reset
 * @property integer $admin
 * @property integer $email_verified
 * @property integer $login_disabled
 */
class User extends CActiveRecord {

    /**
     * Used for password change and registration
     */
    public $pass1;
    public $pass2;
    public $old_password;
    public $verify;
    public $state_name;

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return User the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('email, first_name, last_name', 'required', 'on' => 'create, register'),
            array('email', 'unique'),
            array('email', 'exist', 'on' => 'forgotPassword'),
            array('old_password', 'site.common.components.validate.ECurrentPassword', 'on' => 'changePassword'),
            array((app()->user->isAdmin() ? 'pass1, pass2' : 'old_password, pass1, pass2'), 'required', 'on' => 'changePassword'),
            array('pass1, pass2', 'required', 'on' => 'resetPass'),
            array('pass2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'pass1', 'on' => 'resetPass, changePassword'),
            array('pass1, pass2', 'site.common.components.validate.EPasswordStrength', 'on' => 'resetPass, changePassword'),
            array('password, pass2', 'required', 'on' => 'register'),
            array('pass2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'on' => 'register'),
            //array('verify', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty' => !CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'on' => 'register, forgotPassword'),
           array(
                'validation',
                'site.common.extensions.recaptcha.EReCaptchaValidator',
                'privateKey'=> Yii::app()->params['recaptcha']['privateKey'],
                'on' => 'register, forgotPassword'
            ),
            array('admin, email_verified, login_disabled', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('email, password', 'length', 'max' => 63),
            array('address', 'length', 'max' => 150), //originally 511 
            array('postcode, city, state, state_name', 'length', 'max' => 50),            
            array('phone_area, phone', 'length', 'max' => 10), //originally 12
            array('gender, birthday', 'length', 'max' => 20),        
            array('first_name, last_name', 'length', 'max' => 45),
            array('password_reset', 'numerical', 'on' => 'passwordReset', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('password, pass2', 'site.common.components.validate.EPasswordStrength', 'on' => 'register'),
            array('email', 'email', 'on' => 'update, create, register'),
            array('first_name, last_name', 'site.common.components.validate.ENameValidator'),
            array('email', 'unique', 'on' => 'create, register'),
            array('email, phone', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true), // make empty values stored as NULL
            array('last_login', 'safe'),

            array('username', 'unique', 'on' => 'consumer-reviews'),
            array('username', 'site.common.components.validate.EUsernameValidator', 'on' => 'consumer-reviews'),
            //array('username', 'unique','className'=>'User','attributeName'=>'username','message'=>"Username already exists"),

            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, email, first_name, last_name, phone, admin, email_verified, login_disabled', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'firstname' => 'First Name',
            'lastname' => 'Last Name',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'city' => 'City',
            'state' => 'State',
            'state_name' => 'State',
            'postcode' => 'Poscode',
            'phone_area' => 'Phone Area',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'activate' => 'Activate',
            'last_login' => 'Last Login',
            'password_reset' => 'Password Reset',
            'admin' => 'Admin',
            'email_verified' => 'Email Verified',
            'login_disabled' => 'Login Disabled',
            'pass1' => 'New Password',
            'pass2' => 'Confirm Password',
            'old_password' => 'Current Password',
            'validation'=> 'Are You Human?!',
           // 'verify' => 'Validate',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Automatic add the current time to create_at field once registered 
     */

    public function behaviors(){
      //The createAttribute and updateAttribute options actually default to 'create_time' and 'update_time' respectively
       return array(
          'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
             'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
             'createAttribute' => 'create_at',
             'updateAttribute' => 'last_login',
          )
       );
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);

        return $criteria;
    }

    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->admin;
    }

    public static function findByEmail($email) {
        return self::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $email));
    }

    /**
     * Create new user object, do not save it to database yet
     * all permission should be valid now
     * @param type $input
     */
    public static function create($input) {

        if (isset($input['email'])) {
            $model = self::findByEmail($input['email']);
        } else {
            $model = new User;
        }
        $password = isset($input['password']) ? $input['password'] : '';

        if (null == $model) {
            // used by admin for creating a user (be sure to send the random password to the user...)
            $model = new User;
            $model->attributes = $input;

            if (strlen($model->password) == 0) {
                // create new one if nothing is provided (only applies to admins creating new users)
                $password = Shared::generateMnemonicPassword(8);
            } else {
                $password = $model->password;
            }
            $model->password = crypt($password, Randomness::blowfishSalt());
            $model->pass1 = $password;
            $model->email = strtolower($model->email);
        }
        return $model;
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }

    public function getAvatar() {

            $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);

            $id = $user->id;
            $dir = 'uploads/user';
            $img = $user->avatar_link;
            $full_img_dir = './'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img;

        return (!empty($img) && file_exists($full_img_dir)) 
               ? Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img
               : Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/blank_profile.gif';
    }

    /**
     * Generate an encrypted hash for the user
     * @param type $string
     * @param type $hash
     * @return type
     */
    public static function encrypt($string = "", $hash = "md5") {
        if ($hash == "md5")
            return md5($string);
        if ($hash == "sha1")
            return sha1($string);
        else
            return crypt($hash, $string);
    }

    /**
     * Function called before update. 
     * @param type $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        if (strlen($password) > 0) {
            // change password
            $this->password = crypt($password, Randomness::blowfishSalt());
        } else {
            // keep the original one
            $this->restoreAttribute('password');
        }
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You call non static method as static, using $this without any object, that's your error.
How to achieve what you want?
First you must have User object, to use $this and non static method.

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
```

Next (if you have all fields ofcourse) you can call it:

```
<img class="img-rounded user-avatar" src="<?php echo $user->getAvatar(); ?>" title="<?php echo Yii::app()->user->username; ?>" />
```

In this case your $this in function will be user model, otherwise its controller(in all views $this is controller). Also you can use it as `$user->avatar`, since it's yii getter.

**Edit:**
How to do it with `Yii::app()->user->avatar_link`

**1st.** Make your WebUser class and add it to config in components->user section(i assume it already exists)

```
'user' => array(
          'class' => 'RWebUser',
```

**2nd.** Make getter and setter for avatar_link:

```
public function setAvatar_link($avatar_link)
{
    $this->setState('User_avatar_link', $avatar_link);
}

public function getAvatar_link()
{
    $this->getState('User_avatar_link');
}
```

**3rd.** Add logic to `afterlogin()` to get your avatar link:

```
public function afterLogin($fromCookie)
{
    parent::afterLogin($fromCookie);

    $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);

    $id = $user->id;
    $dir = 'uploads/user';
    $img = $user->avatar_link;
    $full_img_dir = './'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img;

    $avatar_link = (!empty($img) && file_exists($full_img_dir)) 
           ? Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img
           : Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/blank_profile.gif';
    $this->setAvatar_link($avatar_link);
}
```

Now you can use it with `Yii::app()->user->avatar_link`, it will be stored in session and will be 1 more query when user login.

Comment: ok, where do i put `$user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);` in my User.php? Doesn't User.php already do that? I would like to call `Yii::app()->user->avatar_link` but as you can see in my `getAvatar()` i have that if-else statement. sorry new to Yii

Comment: does `findByPk()` create another query that queries my DB? coz $this works on my other views, just not in my header. dont make sense to query the same DB twice. (my humble opinion)

Comment: If you want to use it as `Yii::app()->user->avatar_link` you must set it in your WebUser class into session. As for user, you can do it in controller and pass to view, and yes it's 1 more query. You don't have User object without it anyway.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed explanation! really appreciate it. Just to be clear, the ` afterLogin()` goes in `RWebUser` too right?

Comment: `RWebUser` is your users class, it extends `CWebUser`. You can call it how you want. Since you extending `CWebUser` you can rewrite it's `afterLogin()` method in your class with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Call it like this User::model()->getAvatar() instead of User::getAvatar();